# Windows Registry CREATOR OWNER

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-server-2019

I've got a program that creates a registry key in HKCU, but after that does not have the rights to write to it. It seems to me that CREATOR OWNER does not work.

[image: Permissions]
[image: Effective access]

The strange thing is that it does work on non-server environments (standard Windows 10).

Why do I not have full control, despite being the owner of this key? How do I fix this? (For now I'm just adding my account explicitly, but that's not workable when working with large numbers of keys.)

Answer (score 2):

The Creator Owner account **isn't a real account** but rather **a flag** that the Windows security system uses in a folder's ACL to build the ACLs of files and sub-folders that users create in this folder. NT assigns the permissions that you assign to a folder's Creator Owner account to all accounts that create a new sub-folder or file in that folder.

You should add your desired account to have permissions and everything should be fine.

Comment: Are you saying that if creator owner is set to read-only, anything anyone creates should have a read-only right created for them automatically?

Comment: If something is read-only, you can't create anything there. It can be used to achieve various tricks. Example: In a shared folder, set Creator-owner: Modify, Everyone:Read. Then if you put a document in there, everyone could read it but they wouldn't be able to edit it and mess it up, only you would. Also note that the “Owner” of the object is not the same thing as the “Creator Owner”.